# Having some specific images file and need to copy selected files to another folder

Tags: batch-file, scripting, powershell-2.0

I am new to the coding here,
I was googling out several threads here regarding my requirement, tried but not getting succeeded.

My basic requirement is.
I have a folder having 1000 images.
Need to copy specific images and transfer to some other folder. 
This is the basic basic requiremnet

Open to any way
Either Xcopy or robocopy or powershell

Tried with Xcopy

```
xcopy /d /y /s "\Your Image Folder\*.jpg" "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Master Image Folder\"
```

Here I am getting issues that One file is getting copied fine but not I need to copy several files . How will modify on that script

Tried with robocopy

```
robocopy "source path" "destination path" "file name"
```

same issue , how can I transfer multiple files. 
Say I have listed down the names in excel or notepad.

Tried with PowerShell

```
Get-Content e:\np.txt | ForEach-Object {copy-item $_ E:\day1\sorted}
```

Here, The `NP.txt` - is the list of files in that notepad file.
Now the destination is `E:\day1\sorted`
But I get confused where will be the source path, Where should be the source path, should I write

Answer (score 0):

to read your list, use a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (np.txt) do echo %%a
```

Instead of `echo %%a` (for testing), just insert your copy command:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (np.txt) do (
   xcopy /d /y /s "\Your Image Folder\%%a" "%userprofile%\Desktop\Master Image Folder\"
)
```

(you may have to adapt it a little bit depending on the exact content of `np.txt`. Also, I'm not sure, why you use `/s` - shouldn't be necessary according to your description)